# Mirroring/flipping images in IE and maintain transparency

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I've been experimenting with flipping background images with this css:

```
.flipHorizontal {
    -moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
    -o-transform: scaleX(-1);
    transform: scaleX(-1);
    filter: FlipH;
    -ms-filter: "FlipH";
}
```

Everything works just fine in all browser except for IE when you have a PNG with a transparent background(alpha channel). All transparent and semi-transparent pixel gets completely black.

Anyone knows a workaround for this?

Maybe there is another filter (read "hotfix") that MS implemented to fix this kind of issue. I think the same error applies to rotation and other transformation filters as well with PNG.

Comment: All versions of IE, even the new IE9 beta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the old IE6 `AlphaImageLoader` hack to get what you are looking for, along with another `DXImageTransform` to do the flipping.  Unfortunately, it becomes less generic since you must define the image, but you can dynamically set the style with some script.  (See [here](http://homepage.ntlworld.com/bobosola/pnghowto.htm) for an example of the dynamic scripting -- look for the pngfix.js code.)

```
.flipHorizontal {
   -moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
   -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
   -o-transform: scaleX(-1);
   transform: scaleX(-1);
   filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='myImage.png')
           progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(mirror=1);
}
```

Tested successfully in IE8 and FF3.6.  Not sure you need the -ms-filter, but I couldn't test IE6 or IE7, and am not certain if it needs that attribute.

Comment: I used FlipH to do the magic, since i had to use javascript. IE users will have to switch browser if they want to get rid of the blackness. I might be doing all web developers a favor by forcing some users to quit using IE... Your solution works great if your willing to use javascript to fix it.

Comment: Anyone else using this might want to remove the trailing " on the second filter - (mirror=1)"; - Caused me a little pain!

Comment: The trailing quote that @Gais mentioned has been removed from code.

Answer (score 3):

So, I realize this is 2 years too late.  Sorry.  :)

But for anyone else getting here, try putting a background-color on the css and that should make it happy (or, at least, it fixes it for the same problem when you fade it in and out, I assume it's all the same masking errors).

Comment: Phenomenal solution! Thanks.